# Is there a native way to change web.config settings on build dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net

We're using a library that needs to have a value updated in the web.config with every build. Is there a way to do this natively?

We're using a library that has a custom config section in the web.config

The version attribute needs to be updated with every build. Increment or even DateTime.Now equivalent would work.

```
<clientDependency version="6">
...
</clientDependency>
```

Comment: Can you elobrate on what needs to be updated and why? This seams not beeing best practice. However using the new Task Runner Explorer and the [config "include" feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300063/can-i-create-config-file-and-include-it-to-web-config) it might be possible.

Comment: You can use web config transforms for things like different connection string or credentials for dev / test / prod, but if it's something like a build # that changes every build, you may need a post-build task that manipulates the config file.

Comment: If you meant change on *deploy*, instead of build, you can do transformations. Check this: [How to: Transform Web.config When Deploying a Web Application Project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt I added more detail to the question but yeah doesn't seem like it should have been implemented this way

Comment: @GlennFerrie & Anderson Pimentel It needs to be per build so it will update while we are doing dev and not have to publish everytime we want to see an update locally. Also, the number has to be dynamic so transforms won't work to my knowledge. I updated the OP with more detail

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make Web.config transformations working locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613714/make-web-config-transformations-working-locally)

Comment: @user3953989 you can apply transformations during build with the TransformXML build task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first review, why exactly the config change on every build. This seems not to be good. Maybe you can change this.

However, with Visual Studio 2013 the [Gulp](http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2014/10/08/how-to-use-gulp-in-visual-studio.aspx) Task Runner was introduced.

You could abuse it a little bit.

Basicly:

- [Write a `*.config` file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23230569/how-do-you-create-a-file-from-a-string-in-gulp) on [every build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469364/execute-gulp-js-tasks-post-build-in-vs2015), which includes only the changing settings.
- In your `web.config` you [include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300063/can-i-create-config-file-and-include-it-to-web-config) the `*.config`.

Comment: First, this is neither unusual nor bad. There *are* different builds (Release vs Debug) and environments (Development vs Testing vs Staging vs Production). Second, this is already available in the *deployment* pipeline. You *can* apply different transformations per build *and* environment. There's no need to use external tools.

Comment: In fact, this functionality is supported not only by Visual Studio but deployment tools like Octopus Deploy, Release Management Services etc, in order to make deployment to different environments easier

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Can you provide an example of how to increment that value on each build? I know how to replace it with a static value using transforms

Comment: The same mechanism is also used in NuGet and Chocolatey to apply transformations to config files during deployment

Comment: @Christian Gollhardt I may have to end up doing this if nothing native is available.

Comment: @user3953989 not to my knowledge, if it must be realy on every build. But maybe somebody comes with a better solution

Answer (score 4):

You can try using [MSBuild Tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7z253716.aspx).

Maybe [XMLPoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/xmlpoke-task) to update the `web.config` with a formatted date/time string:

```
<Target Name="EchoTime">
    <Time Format="yyyyMMddHHmmss">
        <Output TaskParameter="FormattedTime" PropertyName="currentTime" />
    </Time>
    <Message Text = "$(currentTime)" />
</Target>

<Target Name="UpdateWebConfig">
  <XmlPoke 
      XmlInputPath="web.config"
      Query="//<complete-path>/clientDependency/@version"
      Value="$(currentTime)" />
</Target>
```

Moving the *updatable* section to an external file, using [`configSource`](https://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/using-configsource-to-split-configuration-files) could also make the job easier.

Answer (score -1):

Here is other sample to do with XmlPoke in MSBuild.

Auto replace VersionBuild value with yyyyMMddmmss when publish

```xml
Web.config
<appSettings>
    <add key="VersionBuild" value=".121"/>
</appSettins>
```

```xml
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <CurrentDate>$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString(yyyyMMddmmss))</CurrentDate>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <XmlPoke 
      Condition="'$(PublishProfileName)' != ''"
      XmlInputPath="Web.config"
      Query="/configuration/appSettings/add[@key = 'VersionBuild']/@value"
      Value=".$(CurrentDate)" />
</Target>
```

Comment: If you wonder why the downvotes - the question that's been asked almost 2 years ago, your answer only contains a link that's already been mentioned.